# simple rss downloader in haskell

Tags: haskell, utf-8, rss

Yesterday i tried to write a simple rss downloader in Haskell wtih hte help of the [Network.HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-3000.0.0) and [Feed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/feed-0.3.8) libraries. I want to download the link from the rss item and name the downloaded file after the title of the item.

Here is my short code:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Network.HTTP
import Text.Feed.Import
import Text.Feed.Query
import Text.Feed.Types
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Network.URI (parseURI, uriToString)

getTitleAndUrl :: Item -> (Maybe String, Maybe String)
getTitleAndUrl item = (getItemTitle item, getItemLink item)

downloadUri :: (String,String) -> IO ()
downloadUri (title,link) = do
  file <- get link
  B.writeFile title file
    where
      get url = let uri = case parseURI url of
                      Nothing -> error $ "invalid uri" ++ url
                      Just u -> u in
                simpleHTTP (defaultGETRequest_ uri) >>= getResponseBody

getTuples :: IO (Maybe [(Maybe String, Maybe String)])
getTuples = fmap (map getTitleAndUrl) <$> fmap (feedItems) <$> parseFeedString <$> (simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://index.hu/24ora/rss/") >>= getResponseBody)
```

I reached a state where i got a list which contains tuples, which contains name and the corresponding link. And i have a `downloadUri` function which properly downloads the given link to a file which has the name of the rss item title.

I already tried to modify `downloadUri` to work on `(Maybe String,Maybe String)` with `fmap`- ing on `get` and `writeFile` but failed with it horribly.

- How can i apply my `downloadUri` function to the result of the `getTuples` function. I want to implement the following main function

  `main :: IO ()`
  `main = some magic incantation donwloadUri more incantation getTuples`
- The character encoding of the result of `getItemTitle` broken, it puts code points in the places of the accented characters. The feed is utf8 encoded, and i thought that all haskell string manipulation functions are defaulted to utf8. How can i fix this?

**Edit:**

Thanks for you help, i implemented successfully my main and helper functions. Here comes the code:

```
downloadUri :: (Maybe String,Maybe String) -> IO ()
downloadUri (Just title,Just link) = do
  item <- get link
  B.writeFile title item
    where
      get url = let uri = case parseURI url of
                      Nothing -> error $ "invalid uri" ++ url
                      Just u -> u in
                simpleHTTP (defaultGETRequest_ uri) >>= getResponseBody
downloadUri _ = print "Somewhere something went Nothing"

getTuples :: IO (Maybe [(Maybe String, Maybe String)])
getTuples = fmap (map getTitleAndUrl) <$> fmap (feedItems) <$> parseFeedString <$> decodeString <$> (simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://index.hu/24ora/rss/") >>= getResponseBody)

downloadAllItems :: Maybe [(Maybe String, Maybe String)] -> IO ()
downloadAllItems (Just feedlist) = mapM_ downloadUri $ feedlist
downloadAllItems _ = error "feed does not get parsed"

main = getTuples >>= downloadAllItems
```

The character encoding issue has been partially solved, i put `decodeString` before the feed parsing, so the files get named properly. But if i want to print it out, the issue still happens. Minimal working example:

```
main = getTuples
```

Comment: I tried running your code, but I'm encountering some trouble with the proxy here at work, so I won't be able to help with the decoding issue until I get home. And even then, it may require someone else's expertise. The UTF8 issue is very different from the `Maybe` issue. What I suggest is that you start a new question for the character encoding issue, and post your minimal working example. That will help to get the right people looking the problem. Also, you might try invoking `simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://index.hu/24ora/rss/")` in GHCi to see how the characters are coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it's the `Maybe`s that are giving you trouble. There are many ways to deal with `Maybe` values, and some useful library functions like `fromMaybe` and `fromJust`. However, the simplest way is to do pattern matching on the `Maybe` value. We can tweak your downloadUri function to work with the `Maybe` values. Here's an example:

```
downloadUri :: (Maybe String, Maybe String) -> IO ()
downloadUri (Just title, Just link) = do
  file <- get link
  B.writeFile title file
    where
      get url = let uri = case parseURI url of
                      Nothing -> error $ "invalid uri" ++ url
                      Just u -> u in
                simpleHTTP (defaultGETRequest_ uri) >>= getResponseBody
downloadUri _ = error "One of my parameters was Nothing".
```

Or maybe you can let the title default to blank, in which case you could insert this just before the last line in the previous example:

```
downloadUri (Nothing, Just link) = downloadUri (Just "", Just link)
```

Now the only `Maybe` you need to work with is the outer one, applied to the array of tuples. Again, we can pattern match. It might be clearest to write a helper function like this:

```
downloadAllItems (Just ts) = ??? -- hint: try a `mapM`
downloadAllItems Nothing = ??? -- don't do anything, or report an error, or...
```

As for your encoding issue, my guesses are:

1. You're reading the information from a file that isn't UTF-8 encoded, or your system doesn't realise that it's UTF-8 encoded.
2. You are reading the information correctly, but it gets messed up when you output it.

In order to help you with this problem, I need to see a full code example, which shows how you're reading the information and how you output it.

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal example for the encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your main could be something like the shown below. There may be some more concise way to compose these two operations though:

```
main :: IO ()
main = getTuples >>= process
       where
           process (Just lst) = foldl (\s v -> do {t <- s; download v}) (return ()) lst 
           process Nothing = return ()
           download (Just t, Just l) = downloadUri (t,l)
           download _ = return ()
```