# fix broken utf8 encoding in haskell

Tags: haskell, utf-8, character-encoding

With the help of the kind SO people, i successfully implemented a [simple rss downloader in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038947/simple-rss-downloader-in-haskell/17044041#17044041).
But one question remains: how to fix the broken encoding of the feed item title?
Here is the minimal working example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Network.HTTP
import Text.Feed.Import
import Text.Feed.Query
import Text.Feed.Types
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Network.URI (parseURI, uriToString)
import Codec.Binary.UTF8.String (decodeString, encodeString)

getTitleAndUrl :: Item -> (Maybe String, Maybe String)
getTitleAndUrl item = (getItemTitle item, getItemLink item)

downloadUri :: (Maybe String,Maybe String) -> IO ()
downloadUri (Just title,Just link) = do
  item <- get link
  B.writeFile title item
    where
      get url = let uri = case parseURI url of
                      Nothing -> error $ "invalid uri" ++ url
                      Just u -> u in
                simpleHTTP (defaultGETRequest_ uri) >>= getResponseBody
downloadUri _ = print "Somewhere something went Nothing"

getTuples :: IO (Maybe [(Maybe String, Maybe String)])
getTuples = fmap (map getTitleAndUrl) <$> fmap (feedItems) <$> parseFeedString <$> decodeString <$> (simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://index.hu/24ora/rss/") >>= getResponseBody)

main = getTuples
```

It prints out like

```
Just [...,(Just "Gyalogosbaleset miatt \225ll a t\246megk\246zleked\233s a Margit h\237don",Just "http://velvet.hu/blogok/helyszinelo/2013/06/18/gyalogossbaleset_miatt_all_a_tomegkozlekedes_a_margit_hidon/"),...]
```

I made some research, the feed has its item titles sorrounded by `<![CDATA[]]`, so the xml parser skips them.

Example item:

```xml
<item>
        <title><![CDATA[Gyalogosbaleset miatt áll a tömegközlekedés a Margit hídon]]></title>
        <link>http://velvet.hu/blogok/helyszinelo/2013/06/18/gyalogossbaleset_miatt_all_a_tomegkozlekedes_a_margit_hidon/</link>
        <pubDate>Tue, 18 Jun 2013 09:08:00 +0200</pubDate>
        <category domain="main"></category>
        <description><![CDATA[A tájékoztatás szerint a budai hídfő megállójában elesett egy gyalogos, jelenleg pótlóbuszok közlekednek.]]></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[A tájékoztatás szerint a budai hídfő megállójában elesett egy gyalogos, jelenleg pótlóbuszok közlekednek.]]></content:encoded>
</item>
```

How can i force utf8 encoding to this string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's the behavior here that you don't like? What does UTF-8 have to do with it? How would it behave differently if it was behaving the way you want?

Comment: @shachaf: t\246megk\246zleked\233s -> tömegközlekedés and so on...

Comment: OK. 1: Haskell `String`s are Unicode strings. They're not UTF-8 or UTF-anything -- they're just lists of Unicode codepoints. 2: You're just looking at the result of `show` for a string. That's how the `Show` instance works -- you're not going to be able to do anything about that. If you print the string -- e.g. with `putStrLn` -- you'll see that it prints fine. The string is correct, it's just that the way you're looking at it escapes some characters.

Comment: @shachaf: Thanks, now i understand it. I would happily accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I'll just copy my comment down here:

1. Haskell Strings are Unicode strings. They're not UTF-8 or UTF-anything -- they're just lists of Unicode codepoints.
2. You're just looking at the result of `show` for a string. That's how the `Show` instance works -- you're not going to be able to do anything about that. If you print the string -- e.g. with `putStrLn` -- you'll see that it prints fine. The string is correct, it's just that the way you're looking at it escapes some characters.